# What are the I2C2 pins in K81F?

Tags: microcontroller

I am trying to understand the pin diagram of K81F and found there are 2 sets of sda and scl lines, I2C1 and I2C2. Are these just different lines to interface 2 sets of I2C buses?

Comment: What is a K81F? It is likely, whatever it is to be two I2C interfaces though.

Comment: NXP Kinetis K81

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two independent I2C controllers and two separate busses, so there also are two sets of SDA/SCL pins.

Comment: There are 4 I2C buses, 2 sets of I2C1 pins with the buses, and 2 sets of I2C2 pins with buses. What does that mean?

Comment: This means that the pin multiplexing controller can connect the internal I2C controller to any of them (possibly also split SDA from one and SCL from other). So you have 2 bus controllers and you can choose to which set of pins each controller is connected. Example: you can have I2C1 SDA on pin 1 or 100 and SCL on pin 2 and 101.